# Easy Blockchain

Tags: java, blockchain

Всем привет. Помогите найти ошибку. Создаю элементарную блокчейн из 5 элементов. Остальной код работает, проверяла без цикла. Я новичек в джаве. Получается, что сохраняется только два хеша первых элементов.

```
    int numberOfBlocks = 5;

    for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfBlocks; i++) {

        String endOfNumber = "";

        if (i == 1)
            blockchain.add(new Block(i + "st block", "0"));
        else {
            switch(i) {
                case 2:
                    endOfNumber = "nd";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    endOfNumber = "rd";
                    break;
                default:
                    endOfNumber = "th";
                    break;
            }
        }

        blockchain.add(new Block(i + endOfNumber + " block", blockchain.get(blockchain.size()-1).hash));
        System.out.println("Try to mine block " + i);   
        blockchain.get(i-1).mineBlock(difficulty);
        System.out.println("Blockchain is Valid: " + isChainValid());
    }

    String blockchainJson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(blockchain);
    System.out.println("The blockchain:\n" + blockchainJson);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тебе нужно занести сохранение блока в ветку `else` после операции `switch`, вот код:

```
    int numberOfBlocks = 5;

    for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfBlocks; i++) {

        String endOfNumber = "";

        if (i == 1)
            blockchain.add(new Block(i + "st block", "0"));
        else {
            switch(i) {
                case 2:
                    endOfNumber = "nd";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    endOfNumber = "rd";
                    break;
                default:
                    endOfNumber = "th";
                    break;
            }

            blockchain.add(new Block(i + endOfNumber + " block", blockchain.get(blockchain.size()-1).hash));
        }

        System.out.println("Try to mine block " + i);   
        blockchain.get(i-1).mineBlock(difficulty);
        System.out.println("Blockchain is Valid: " + isChainValid());
    }
    String blockchainJson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(blockchain);
    System.out.println("The blockchain:\n" + blockchainJson);
```

В твоем примере, происходит следующее : ты создаешь 1 блок, потом завершается оператор `if` и ты исполняешь новое сохранение блока, из-за чего вся цепочка перестает быть валидной.